# expected conv2d to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape

Tags: python, keras, medical, unet-neural-network

I am trying to perform a convolutional network on some medical images that have **nifti** format, using **Keras**.  When I try to fit the model like this:

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
      batch_size=batch_size, 
      epochs = n_epoch, 
      validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

I get this error:

> expected conv2d_171 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (1240, 240, 240)

But when I change the input size from `img_channels = 4` to this:

```
img_channels = 3
img_rows = 240
img_cols = 240
```

I get another error:

> expected input_8 to have shape (240, 240, 3) but got array with shape (240, 240, 4)

The size of the images is like this:

[image]

should I resize the images? or flip the order of image elements?

This is the code for the model:

```
    inputs = Input((img_rows, img_cols, img_channels))
    s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (s)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
```

Comment: 4 dimensions means that your input shape should be something like `(1240, 240, 240, 3)` instead of `(1240, 240, 240)`. `(1240, 240, 240)` itself is 3 dimensions. The dimension has nothing to do with the image channel value.

Comment: Please include the full model code, the problem is in your targets.

Comment: @JiashenCao So it doesn't have anything to do with channels. I changed it back to 4 channels. But why am I getting the error, while `X_train` is 4-dimensional?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad I think this error `expected conv2d_171 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1240, 240, 240)` is complaining about one of your layer shape. Which layer is `conv2d_171`?

Comment: @JiashenCao it changes every time I run the program. Once it says conv2d_171, now it says conv2d_190. I think the problem might be with the size of `Y_train` which is `(1240, 240, 240)`

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad That might be it. Also in Keras, if you do not specify a name for each layer, Keras itself will try to assign a name. And if the previous model is not cleaned up internally, the `conv2d_{number}` will keep increasing. Though the name is different, it could still point to the same layer.

Comment: @JiashenCao I added names to the layers. It is the output layer which gives the error. `outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using a Unet for segmentation. The problem is with your labels, each of which should be a 3D matrice like `(width, height, num_classes)`. So with the sample length, it should be `(sample_length, width, height, num_classes)`.

In your case, transform them as `(310, 240, 240, num_classes)`. If the label/target images are binary, `num_classes=1`. Otherwise, you might need to do some preprocessing on the annotated images and one-hot encode them into `num_classes`.

Also, have a look if you are building up the computation graph multiple times because `conv2d_171` seems to be quite a high number. I don't see that many layers in your architecture.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I changed it to `Y_train[:,:,:,np.newaxis]` and the error went away. I will try `num_classes` as well which I think is the right way to go.

Comment: Nice, happy to help